# Moving median filter (medfilt) in C

Tags: algorithm, c, signal-processing

I have implemented a Moving Median Filter and I would like a review.

I am using a linked list to keep track of the oldest value in the kernel and an array of nodes `sorted` which is sorted.

The `sorted` pointed is stored along the `MedfiltNode` because it saves one array. It is a bit ugly though.

Regarding the sorting algorithm. It is a half-bubble-sort implementation where the value is either bubbled toward the top of the bottom of the sorted list. Average complexity is `N/2`. Depending on the kernel size it might worth using a binary-insertion-sort algorithm instead, but I would like to avoid to use any recursive algorithm.

#### Header

```
/**
* Moving Median Filter.
*
* This algorithm is iterative. Each call will compute the next point.
* In the example below, the kernel has a size of 3. Notice that the
* values in the kernel are alway sorted. The left value is therefore
* the minimum in the kernel, the center value is the median and the
* right value is the maximum value.
*
* Input data:         0 1 2 5 4 8 3
* Kernel:      |0 0 0|            .   (min=0, med=0, max=0)
*                |0 0 0|          .   (min=0, med=0, max=0)
*                  |0 0 1|        .   (min=0, med=0, max=1)
*                    |0 1 2|      .   (min=0, med=1, max=2)
*                      |1 2 5|    .   (min=1, med=2, max=5)
*                        |2 4 5|  .   (min=2, med=4, max=5)
*                          |4 5 8|.   (min=4, med=5, max=8)
*                            |3 4 8|  (min=3, med=4, max=8)
*/
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MedfiltNode {
    float value;
    size_t index; // Node index in the sorted table
    struct MedfiltNode* parent;
    struct MedfiltNode* sorted;
} MedfiltNode;

typedef struct MedfiltData {
    MedfiltNode *kernel; // Working filter memory
    MedfiltNode *oldest; // Reference to the oldest value in the kernel
    size_t length; // Number of nodes
} MedfiltData;

void median_init(MedfiltData *data, MedfiltNode *nodes, size_t length);
void median(float input, MedfiltData *data, float *median, float *min, float *max);
```

#### Source Code

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "medfilt.h"

static void swap(MedfiltNode **a, MedfiltNode **b) {
    // Swap two node references in the sorted table.
    MedfiltNode *temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;

    // Preserve index. Used to retrive the node position in the sorted table.
    size_t index = (*a)->index;
    (*a)->index = (*b)->index;
    (*b)->index = index;
}

void median(float input, MedfiltData *data, float *median, float *min, float *max) {
    // New value replaces the oldest
    MedfiltNode *n = data->kernel;
    MedfiltNode *node = data->oldest;
    node->value = input;
    data->oldest = node->parent;

    // Sort the kernel
    #define VAL(x) (n[x].sorted->value)
    for (size_t i = node->index; i < data->length - 1 && VAL(i) > VAL(i + 1); i++) {
        swap(&n[i].sorted, &n[i + 1].sorted);
    }

    for (size_t i = node->index; i > 0 && VAL(i) < VAL(i - 1); i++) {
        swap(&n[i].sorted, &n[i - 1].sorted);
    }

    // Get kernel information from sorted entries
    *min = n[0].sorted->value;
    *max = n[data->length - 1].sorted->value;
    *median = n[data->length / 2].sorted->value;
}

void median_init(MedfiltData *data, MedfiltNode *nodes, size_t length) {
    data->kernel = nodes;
    data->length = length;

    // Linked list initialization
    data->oldest = &data->kernel[length - 1];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; data->oldest = &data->kernel[i], i++) {
        data->kernel[i] = (MedfiltNode) {
            .value = 0,
            .parent = data->oldest,
            .index = i,
            .sorted = &data->kernel[i]
        };
    }
}
```

#### Test program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "medfilt.h"

static void kernel2str(MedfiltData *data) {
    printf("[ ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < data->length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", (int)data->kernel[i].sorted->value);
    }
    printf("]");
}

static void display(MedfiltData *data, size_t i, int in, int min, int mid, int max) {
    printf("u[%d] = %d -> min=%d mid=%d max=%d kernel=", (int)i, in, min, mid, max);
    kernel2str(data);
    printf("\n");
}


#define KERNEL  (5)

int main(void) {
    const int in[] = { 3, 1, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1 };

    MedfiltData data;
    MedfiltNode nodes[KERNEL];
    medfilt_init(&data, nodes, KERNEL);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(in) / sizeof(in[0]); i++) {
        float min, mid, max;
        medfilt(in[i], &data, &mid, &min, &max);
        display(&data, i, in[i], (int)min, (int)mid, (int)max);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### GitHub project

https://github.com/nowox/moving-median

Comment: Mini-review (I haven't had the time I expected): it would be good to `#undef VAL` once you've finished with it.  Not a problem, just a good habit to be in.  (I'm surprised you didn't continue to use it for the final three statements in that function...)

Comment: @TobySpeight Good remark. I forgot about the last three statements. I mainly used this macro for readability to be below the 80 chars limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Presentation

Code formatted and presented well.  Refreshing.  Compiled properly - almost.

### Initialization

With `median_init()`, the queue is pre-populated with the value of 0.   This implies that the return values of `min,median,max` are all bogus until `n` values added.  it would make sense to either

1. Allow an initialization value: `median_init(...., float init_value)`
2. Or better, functions on `min,median,max` as if it had less than `n` elements are in it until `n` elements are added.

### Complexity

Instead of the structures involved, this task could be solved with less data usage: a length, eldest index and a single array as below and still maintain O(n) complexity.  Adding is a simple as scanning for the eldest index in a sorted array, replacing it with the new value.  Then bubble sort the new value into place.

```
typedef struct MedfiltDataAlt {
    float value;
    size_t queue_order;
} MedfiltDataAlt;
```

### Allocation responsibility

This code obliges the calling code to provide the space needed.  This fine.  Yet I find it more useful for the `median_...()` functions to handle that.  OP's choice on this, just wanted to provide an alternative [POV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_view_(philosophy)).

### Added functionality

A means to report the  `min,median,max` without adding a new number would be useful.

### Parameter order

I'd expect the state data first.

```
// void median(float input, MedfiltData *data, float *median, float *min, float *max)
   void median(MedfiltData *data, float input, float *median, float *min, float *max)
```

### NAN

As `float` can take on a value of [not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).  Code's use of `>` and `<` does not clearly push the `NAN` is a proscribed manner. When NANs are involved, `>` is not the opposite of `<=`.  If code was amended to deal with a growing array during the first `n` calls of `median()`, consider a `median(NAN, ...)` to have the effect of shortening the queue and not saving the NAN.

### Naming

The .c file (assume `medfilt.c` to match `medfilt.h`) name, the type names and function names would be more uniform if they all began with the same prefix *and case* rather than `Medfilt`, `median` and `medfilt`.

This is manifested in the minor code error in `main.c`

```
// medfilt_init(&data, nodes, KERNEL);
median_init(&data, nodes, KERNEL);
```

### Portability

`#pragma once` is not   defined in the C standard

### Function at 0

Minor: Both `median()` and `median_init()` fail with a size of 0.  I would expect code to tolerate this edge case and not cause *undefined behavior*.

### display()

Minor: I'd expect code to use `"%zu"` to match `size_t` or a cast to a wide *unsigned* type to maintain same sign-ness.  Also `int min, int mid, int max` --> `float min, float mid, float max` and use `"%g"` or `"%e"`.  A goal of `display` is diagnostic.  It should avoid data truncation.

```
// printf("u[%d] =...", (int)i, ...);
printf("u[%zu] =...", i, ...);
printf("u[%lu] =...", (unsigned long)i, ...);
```

Comment: Right, I renamed `median` into `medfilt` at last, but forgot to do it properly. I also tried to build it with full MISRA-C3 compatibility and I discovered some issues.  I should have used a `typedef Float32 float` du to the lack of native `float32_t`. `#pragma once` is not yet a standard, but it is supported by all the compilers I am using (Keil, IAR, gcc, clang, armgcc) and again MISRA complains about it. Protecting `median_init` against a size of 0 is a good advise. `NaN` is good advise too. I should add an init value. Good code review, thanks very much :)

Comment: I don't know how to deal with `Allocation responsibility` in pure C. I thought about this question and came with 3 different implementations: 1. Fully static array defined with a  `#define KERNEL_SIZE (N)`, unfortunately not possible to build a modular library with that. 2. Dynamic allocation, proper `medfilt_create`, but requires `medfilt_destroy` at the end, and still issue with the allocation responsability. 3. The current implementation. This code will for sure be more elegant written in C++ and with the use of templates, however I would loose it for MCU embedded applications.

Comment: About `O(n) complexity`, I wanted to avoid iterating over the whole kernel to find the eldest. Your solution looks interesting and it would make me benchmark different approaches. I take your parameters order suggestion.

Comment: I updated the GitHub project with most of your suggestions.

Comment: @nowox  If `n` is sizable, perhaps spend effort going for a `log2(n)` solution.  More complex and more memory, yet do-able.

Comment: @nowox Consider `medfilt_init(MedfiltData *data, MedfiltNode *nodes, float init, size_t length);` --> `medfilt_init(MedfiltData *data, MedfiltNode *nodes, size_t length, float init);` to keep the array and its size adjacent.

Comment: This is a good remark :)